# My anchor tags borders are outside of the parent nav element

Tags: html, css

Here's the problem, the nav elements can **vertically** extend outside of their parent element. I'm asking specifically how the `<a>` tags tend to extend outside of their wrapping `<nav>` parent
[Image showing the borders of the two elements and the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs7Ux.png)

```css
nav {
  padding: 0em 1em 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.head nav a {
  padding: .5em .5em;
  font-size: .9em;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.head nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Latest News</a>
  <a href=""> Upcoming Events</a>
  <a href="">Official </a>
  <a href="">Domestic Rowing</a>
  <a href="">High Performance</a>
  <a href="">Coaching</a>
  <a href="">Resources</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where is the underline coming from?

Comment: @Rojo border-bottom

Comment: Oh yeah skipped over that oops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block` to your anchors.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

nav {
  padding: 0em 1em 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em .5em;
  font-size: .9em;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Latest News</a>
  <a href=""> Upcoming Events</a>
  <a href="">Official </a>
  <a href="">Domestic Rowing</a>
  <a href="">High Performance</a>
  <a href="">Coaching</a>
  <a href="">Resources</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `border-bottom`, you can put another number at the beginning to control the width. This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_border-bottom.asp#midcontentadcontainer) might work. Shows how `border-bottom:` can be used.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about the border's - my problem is that the<a> tags take up more vertical space than their parent <nav>. Why does the <nav> not expand vertically to wrap around it's children.

Comment: @HaydenShaw Then you can just use `min-height: ;`

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
nav {
    padding: 0em 1em 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

solution:

```
nav {
    padding: 0em 1em 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

it won't extend to the bottom now, you'll just need to adjust the`width` of your `nav` to your choice